# Python - How to get only the numbers from a string which has got commas in between

Tags: python

Consider like I have a string :

```
stringA = "values-are-10,20,30,40,50"
stringB = "values-are-10"
```

I need to get only the strings :
desired output :

```
for stringA: 10,20,30,40,50
for stringB: 10
```

I tried using this - `int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, stringA)))`

But it removed all the commas, please let me know how to get the output in that format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `re.findall` here is your friend:

```py
stringA = "values-are-10,20,30,40,50"
stringB = "values-are-10"
strings = [stringA, stringB]
output = [re.findall(r'\d+(?:,\d+)*', s)[0] for s in strings]
print(output)  # ['10,20,30,40,50', '10']
```

Comment: I dont want it to be in combined array. I would like to have different output for String A and String B

Comment: Then use, e.g. for `stringA`: `re.findall(r'\d+(?:,\d+)*', stringA)[0]`

Comment: Thank you. Can you please help if the string is like : 
stringA = "values-are-10-2, 20-1, 30-4, 40-2, 50-1"

Comment: Use: `re.findall(r'\d+(?:-\d+)*, string)[0]`

Comment: I got only 10-2.  could you please help in getting all the ones

Comment: like 10-2, 20-1, 30-4, 40-2, 50-1, if the output needs to be like this , can you please help in proving the regex

Comment: I have given you the regex in the above comment.  If that's not enough, then I suggest opening a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242950/discussion-between-wanderors-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: Why not `search` instead of `findall`? The latter looks somewhat misleading to me here.

Comment: @KellyBundy I chose `re.findall` because it lets us do a one-liner.

Comment: [So does re.search](https://tio.run/##ZY5BCsIwEEX3OcVQF2k1lWgVRBDRa8Qsiqa2oE2YJIKnjyPGhbj6MO/9z7hn6O3YbBymNNydxQBoGPMBh/F6gB0Uj/YWja9bNPVCiqUUjRQrKdayyNbxz/oST0TlKQHZ1szG4GJ4MzRzb1o89yXy02VW7reCoppysislNXQWwcMw5rLXzFGG8jNRAUxA8d@3qEsXrlN6AQ). I only added the import and replaced `findall` with `search`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
[int(v) for v in stringA.rsplit("-", 1)[-1].split(",")]
```

`rsplit` splits from the right - all numbers appear after the last `"-"`. Then we `split` by `","`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Add regex package
import re

stringA = "values-are-10,20,30,40,50"
stringB = "values-are-10"
#search using regex
A = re.findall('[0-9]+', stringA)
print(A) # ['10', '20', '30', '40', '50']
B = re.findall('[0-9]+', stringB)
print(B) # ['10']
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's guaranteed that the initial string will always have the format,
prefix + values, why not just substring this out, a simple
`stringA, stringB = stringA[len(prefixA):], stringB[len(prefixB):];`
and then,
`list1, list2 = [int(num) for num in stringA.split(',')], [int(num) for num in stringB.split(',')];`
should do the job...